# Xamarin Android Localization not changing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, localization

I have created a folder `values-fr` for French localization and placed `String.xml` with french strings in it. When I change the language in my testing device to french it's not changing. PS: `Xamarin` Android.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Could you check what is the value of `Resources.Configuration.Locale;` ?

Comment: check locale configuration

Comment: @MartinZikmund Where can i find this file im new to xamarin. In android studio i wont do any extra configurations. Pl enlighten me

Comment: @G.hakim where i need to check

Comment: It is not a file, it is a property so for example put it at the start of `OnCreate` method in `MainActivity` and then check using the debugger - what is the value of `Locale` property :-) .

Comment: @MartinZikmund i searched my entire project and i cant able to find that. Should i need to configure by myself?

Comment: You should have an `Activity` there (which should have a `OnCreate` method). For example if I create a new Android project from File -> New Project, I get a `MainActivity.cs` file which has the `OnCreate` method prepared. You can then put something like `Log.Debug("Test", Resources.Configuration.Locale.ToString());` at the beginning after `base.OnCreate(bundle)` call

Comment: @SivakumarPurushothaman i would suggest you upload your code for language change that would be easier

Comment: @MartinZikmund it shows as fr_FR, But my folder name is values-fr. am i doing in correct way

Comment: That should still work. In which folder have you put the `values-fr` folder?

Comment: @SivakumarPurushothaman Does it work if you change the file name to `strings.xml`? Localization works fine in my project, but the files in the local folders are all named `strings.xml`, and not `String.xml`.

Comment: @MartinZikmund in Resources

Comment: That should be fine as well. Could you post some code of how you are using some string from the Strings.xml? And have you set the `French` language as the system default (meaning it is the first in the list of languages in settings and the whole system is in french?)

Comment: @sme it has nothing to do with that

Comment: @sme if i change from String.xml to string.xml in plain values folder im getting values not found error.

Comment: In Visual Studio, can you make sure the build action of the `String.xml` file is AndroidResource?

Comment: @MartinZikmund in xml designing im using it as @string/name for android:text property

Comment: The last suggestion from @sme is a good thing to check.

Comment: Yes People Thats the mistake... This proves me that im a KG student in xamarin.... Thanks all for you time and valuable inputs......

Answer (score 0):

Just to post the answer from the comments.

Try this to get the Locale language (just to check), put it in to OnCreate() method:

```
Android.Content.Res.Configuration conf = res.Configuration; 
var languageCodeValue = conf.Locale;
```

if the language it's ok, then check the folder name, you can see more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization

Then check the name of the file, Xaml can't recognize the UpperCase, so you need to define all in minus, check if you have named the file **strings.xml**